enablePassingNulls(true) not working when migrated to springboot 3.2.3
for(Parameter param : storedProcedureQuery. getParameters() {
(ProcedureParameterImpl) parameter). enablePassingNulls (true). 

After migrating to springboot 3.2.3 this method not working. Any alternative way for enablePassingNulls?

First: please give enough code to reproduce your problem. Second: give the full error stack trace. Third: Tell us what you expect and not only that something doesn't work. Also: [ask]
